# Pointers in stl::map

Tags: c++

I have query regarding std::map.

if I have a std::map like:

```
std::map <T1, T2*> my_map;
T1 t;
T2* tt = new T2;
my_map[t]=tt;
```

who is responsible to clean this container,  Will destructor of T2 will take care of it (T2* tt). Also if I want to retain this container throughout the program, where should I clean it.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The map destroys the objects stored in the map. The map stores some `T1` objects, which will be destroyed, and it stores some `T2` pointers, which will be destroyed.

But it does **not** store actual `T2` objects. So no `T2` objects will be destroyed.

Raw pointers do not have ownership of the objects they point to. So when a pointer is destroyed, it will not delete whatever it points to.

Generally speaking, when you have a pointer, there is no way to know if

- it points to a valid object *at all* (you don't want to call `delete` on some random garbage in memory),
- the object it points to has been allocated with `new` (if it has been allocated in another way, it should not be deleted with `delete`), or
- if there are other pointers that also point to the same object (in which case only *one* of them should call `delete`. Which one?)

So even if you wanted to, there is no way to automatically delete an object when a pointer to it is destroyed.

Comment: +1 because this answer is really well written, in-depth, and understandable.

Answer (score 4):

The destructor of `T2` is called nowhere in this example, only the pointer is destroyed. When the map is out of scope, it will destroy all pairs of elements `<T1, T2*>`, but this will not call `delete` on the second item.

You could however use `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (C++11) if you want reference-counted pointers.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
std::map <T1, boost::shared_ptr<T2> > my_map;
T1 t;
T2 *tt = new T2;
my_map[t] = tt; // tt is passed to a shared_ptr, ref count = 1

// when out of scope, the destructor of `boost::shared_ptr` will call `delete`.
```

If you needn't make copies of the objects stored in the map, you can use C++11's `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: In C++11, `unique_ptr` would be more suitable than `shared_ptr`, since shared ownership isn't required.

Comment: @Mike Seymour: with `unique_ptr` some algorithms might be unavailable (that make an object copy) since `unique_ptr(unique_ptr&) = delete;`.

Comment: @Benoit: but until you know you need shared ownership, I'd prefer to default to the safer, more restricted, `unique_ptr`. It's easier to relax the ownership rules later on, than it is to try to tighten them.

Answer (score 1):

What Benoit said; but as an alternative consider a [`boost::ptr_map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_map.html); basically a map which takes ownership of contained pointer values.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you to decide who is responsible to clean data, depending on what is your intent (for instance, your map can be a temporary storage to help perform some algorithm and you want to avoid copies). However, using `boost::shared_ptr` (or `std::tr1::shared_ptr`) is often the good way to go.

Answer (score -1):

This object is a local variable created in the stack(in other words not in the heap). Once it's out of scope, it will be destroyed.

To explain a bit more, when you create an object with `new` operator it's created in the heap, and you have to manually `delete` it. When you instantiate it like `AClass a` this will be created in the stack and when the program flow gets out of the scope it's created it will be destroyed automatically.

Comment: Did I say so? Ruchi asks who cleans up the container? And container `std::map <T1, T2*> my_map;` is created in the stack.

Comment: "Will destructor of T2 will take care of it (T2* tt)", your answer is now true (after the edit) but you should probably change "This object" to "The std::map" since it's a bit vague at the moment.  Also only part of the std::map is on the stack, it's backed by the heap and it's own destructor will clear that up when it goes out of scope.